# Selective tables/objects Oracle Backup

Tags: oracle, backup

I need to automate a selective table / user object backup I currently am doing via PL / SQL Developer.

The way I currently do it is via Tools/Export Tables and Tools/Export User Objects, manually select tables / objects, then set the options, choose destination and export. I do this from a windows laptop and the database is located in a suse linux server, both are in the same LAN. DB is running 24/7 and can not be shutdown. Also currently my oracle programming skills are very basic as I only do maintenance to this solution. I would like to keep doing the backup process in the windows laptop, but I would consider a server side script solution also and then retrieving the .sql files from server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't really call it a backup, but look at exp/imp and expdp/impdp (data pump) in the [Utilities](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/toc.htm) manual

Answer (score 0):

As Gary implies exp/imp really isn't a backup solution.  If this database is important to you or others, figure out how to use [RMAN](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14193/toc.htm) , which is usually configured to run in a mode that doesn't require the database to be shut down.  Although it executes on the database host and for non-tape destinations must write its files to a filesystem attached to the host, it can be launched remotely.

RMAN is aimed at restoring/recovering the entire database, so if what you're looking for is only the ability to recover  isolated objects it may not be for you.

Comment: yes I need a solution to backup / recover isolated objects. Thanks for answer anyway.